# Convenient way to access variables label after importing Stata data with haven

Tags: r, label, stata, r-haven

In R, some packages (e.g. `haven`) insert a `label` attributes to variables (e.g. `haven`), which explains the substantive name of the variable. For example, `gdppc` may have the label `GDP per capita`.

This is extremely useful, especially when importing data from Stata. However, I still struggle to know how to use this in my workflow.

1. How to quickly browse the variable and the variable label? Right now I have to do `attributes(df$var)`, but this is hardly convenient to get a glimpse (a la `names(df)`)
2. How to use these labels in plots? Again, I can use `attr(df$var, "label")` to access the string label. However, it seems cumbersome.

Is there any official way to use these labels in a workflow? I can certainly write a custom function that wraps around the `attr`, but it may break in the future when packages implement the `label` attribute differently. Thus, ideally I'd want an official way supported by `haven` (or other major packages).

Comment: You could create something like a matching table, e.g. `lbs <- setNames(_labels_, names(df))`; then accessing the label can be done via, e.g., `lbs["var"]`

Comment: Various package authors have implemented it differently. The _de_facto_ R standard would be the `read.dta` function in pkg:foreign. `haven` is a relatively recent package and at the moment it doesn't seem to have documented plans for labels.

Comment: @42- `read_dta` in `haven` does have label. In contrast, `foreign::read.dta` actually doesn't. Also, the `foreign` packages does not work with Stata 13, let alone 14.

Comment: Your question has no example. The help page for `read.dta` says the value will be: `"A data frame with attributes. These will include "datalabel", "time.stamp", "formats", "types", "val.labels", "var.labels" and "version" and may include "label.table" and "expansion.table"`.

Comment: You asked about the "official"/idiomatic way of dealing with labels, which is probably best found in `foreign`. Glancing through the `foreign` doc, they suggest the readstata13 package for later versions of Stata. Presumably it also conforms to whatever idiom/norm is found in foreign.

Comment: @42- I stand corrected, `foreign` does have a `var.labels` attribute that is attached to the data frame. This is different from `haven`, but this shows your point that there are different implementations.

Comment: @Heisenberg You might be able to help with this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787126/convenient-way-to-write-variables-label-to-csv-after-importing-stata-data-wit

Answer (score 17):

A solution with [purrr package from tidyverse](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr):

```
df %>% map_chr(~attributes(.)$label)
```

Answer (score 9):

Using sapply in a simple function to return a variable list as in Stata's Variable Window:

```
library(dplyr)
makeVlist <- function(dta) { 
     labels <- sapply(dta, function(x) attr(x, "label"))
      tibble(name = names(labels),
             label = labels)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the innovations addressed in [rio](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rio/index.html) (full disclosure: I wrote this package). Basically, it provides various ways of importing variable labels, including haven's way of doing things and foreign's. Here's a trivial example:

Start by making a reproducible example:

```
> library("rio")
> export(iris, "iris.dta")
```

Import using `foreign::read.dta()` (via `rio::import()`):

```
> str(import("iris.dta", haven = FALSE))
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "datalabel")= chr ""
 - attr(*, "time.stamp")= chr "15 Jan 2016 20:05"
 - attr(*, "formats")= chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 - attr(*, "types")= int  255 255 255 255 253
 - attr(*, "val.labels")= chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 - attr(*, "var.labels")= chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 - attr(*, "version")= int -7
 - attr(*, "label.table")=List of 1
  ..$ Species: Named int  1 2 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Read in using `haven::read_dta()` using its native variable attributes because the attributes are stored at the data.frame level rather than the variable level:

```
> str(import("iris.dta", haven = TRUE, column.labels = TRUE))
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     :Class 'labelled'  atomic [1:150] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Read in using `haven::read_dta()` using an alternative that we (the rio developers) have found more convenient:

```
> str(import("iris.dta", haven = TRUE))
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "var.labels")=List of 5
  ..$ Sepal.Length: NULL
  ..$ Sepal.Width : NULL
  ..$ Petal.Length: NULL
  ..$ Petal.Width : NULL
  ..$ Species     : NULL
 - attr(*, "label.table")=List of 5
  ..$ Sepal.Length: NULL
  ..$ Sepal.Width : NULL
  ..$ Petal.Length: NULL
  ..$ Petal.Width : NULL
  ..$ Species     : Named int  1 2 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
```

By moving the attributes to be at the level of the data.frame, they're much easier to access using `attr(data, "label.var")`, etc. rather than digging through each variable's attributes.

Note: the values of attributes will be NULL because I'm just writing a native R dataset to a local file in order to make this reproducible.

Comment: Do you use `rio` in your own workflow? How committed is the team to staying up to date with all the IO packages that you guys wrap around? I'd love to have a centralized package like this (hence I tried `haven`), but worry about future reproducibility.

Comment: @Heisenberg We are very committed to keeping things up to date and I am very sensitive to backwards/forwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution with the [labelled](http://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/labelled.html) package (tidyverse)

```
descriptions <- var_label(data_raw) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  gather(key = variable, value = description)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the haven package to force to a factor

```
haven::as_factor(df$var, levels="label")
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the [labelled](https://cran.r-project.org/package=labelled) package is to provide convenient functions to manipulate variable and value labels as imported with `haven`.

In addition, the functions `lookfor` and `describe` from the `questionr` package are also useful to display variable and value labels.