# Extract Value Labels from a Stata file loaded with Haven (Value Labels not Variable Labels)

Tags: r, r-haven

I am trying to get a list of the value labels from a data.frame I loaded with haven.  My variables are stored as haven_labelled and I know that the value labels are there because when I run `str()` they are listed as an attribute.

```
 str( x$tranwork )
 'haven_labelled' num [1:498381] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "label")= chr "Means of transportation to work"
 - attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%24.0g"
 - attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:19] 0 10 11 12 13 14 15 20 30 31 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:19] "N/A " "Auto, truck, or van" "Auto" "Driver" ...
>
```

There seem to be alot of good ways to get the variable label.  I can't figure out how to get the value label [Variable labels in the R package Haven with SPSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48818985/variable-labels-in-the-r-package-haven-with-spss) or [Convenient way to access variables label after importing Stata data with haven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817457/convenient-way-to-access-variables-label-after-importing-stata-data-with-haven)

I have tried converting variables to factors, and

```
attr( x$tranwork , "label" )
[1] "Means of transportation to work"
> attr( x$tranwork , "names" )
NULL
```

Essentially I would like to see the label associated with x$transwork 1- through 19

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to get the value labels.

With the `labelled` package:

```
library(labelled)
names(val_labels(x$tranwork))
```

With the `sjlabelled` package:

```
sjlabelled::get_labels(x$tranwork)
```

With `base`:

```
names(attr(x$tranwork, "labels"))
```

If you want to see the value labels along with the values, then use:

```
labelled::val_labels(x$tranwork)
```

or

```
attr(x$tranwork, "labels")
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a dataframe with an overview of the variables and their corresponding labels use:

```
ids = attr(x$tranwork, "labels")
labels = names(attr(x$tranwork, "labels"))

df <- data.frame(id = ids, label = labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to convert the vector into its labels, using

```
x$transwork_labels <- labelled::to_character(x$transwork)
```